# How to remove service from docker-compose.yml programmatically?

Tags: bash, docker-compose

I am creating a bash-script that deletes a docker service. 
I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
   service_1:
     image: vendor/some_image

   service_2:
     image: vendor/some_image
     volumes:
       - ../service_2/www:/var/www

   service_3:
     image: vendor/some_image
     volumes:
       - ../service_3/www:/var/www
       - ../service_3/tests:/test
```

I want to delete some service (for example service_2) from this file to get this:

```
version: '2'

services:
   service_1:
     image: vendor/some_image

   service_3:
     image: vendor/some_image
     volumes:
       - ../service_3/www:/var/www
       - ../service_3/tests:/test
```

How can I do this? Does `docker-compose` have some command for this? 
Maybe I can do it using `sed` or `awk`? The problem is I can't use third party software because an environment where my bash-script will be executed may not have it.

UPD:
The `docker-compose.yml` file has a lot of services (>50). All services should be up at every time. But sometimes some service does not required any more. I write script that remove the service (stop container, clear configs, remove source files, drop databases, etc) for ever. The last step of service deleting process is removing it in `docker-compose.yml` because it is unnecessary to keep it there.

Comment: This is a bit of an X-Y problem, I think: how does the docker-compose file come to have the redundant service in there? What's stopping you from writng a script (or a make file) that will only start the services you need? (runnign `docker-compose up service_1 service_3` will skip `service_2`)... give a bit more details on why you need this, and show us what you've tried

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thank you, I update the question

Answer (score 0):

you can start only the services you name, for example to start `service_1` and `service_3` you can run:

`docker-compose up service_1 service_3`

If you want to edit the docker-compose file you can simply edit it in a text editor and remove the services you don't want. Programmatically, you can do that using `python` and `PyYaml` library.

You can also use `awk` to remove the services, but requires a bit more work...

Comment: Thank you for answer but I can't use python or another third party software because it might be not installed on system

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov then install it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, different environments has different way to install it but I try to create script universal. Besides, I am trying to keep system as clear as possible and not to install programms that are necessary only for operations.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov If I may ask, why do you need to delete the services from the docker-compose file in the first place, when you can simply just start the named services?

Comment: @user7440787,  because I want to keep docker-compose.yml actual and deleted service will not need anymore at all

Comment: There is a lot of services in my docker-compose.yml file and I think that it will be wrong to start some of them while another ones will never start again

Answer (score 0):

I write bash script that delete service from `docker-compose.yml`. The main idea is to read `docker-compose.yml` line by line and compare string with service declaration start. Lines are put to temp file until service declaration is found. Once service declaration has found script stops to print lines to the temp file. When the next service declaration found script starts to print lines to the temp file again. After that temp file copies to the source file.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE_NAME=$1
tmp=$(mktemp)

service_start_regex="^\s{3}$SERVICE_NAME:\s*$"
next_service_start_regex="^\s{3}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+:\s*$"

state="loud"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $service_start_regex ]]; then
        state="silent"
    fi

    if [[ "$line" =~ $next_service_start_regex && ! "$line" =~ $service_start_regex && "$state" == "silent" ]]; then
        state="loud"
    fi

    if [[ $state == "loud" ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done < ./docker-compose.yml > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" docker-compose.yml
```